# Автоматическая сортировка строк в Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Есть таблица:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Необходимо настроить автоматическую сортировку по столбцу B, а именно как вы понимаете "B2". И вот один из вариантов, как я пытаюсь это реализовать способами VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    [B2].CurrentRegion.Sort [B2], xlAscending, Key2:=[C2], Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

И посмотрите, что он мне делает при вводе в ячейку B4 -> 2:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Перепробовал различные варианты, но у меня никак не выходит. Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

А не пробовали проверить адрес региона, над которым происходит сортировка? Зря, ибо в нем и кроется ответ.

```
Debug.Print [B2].CurrentRegion.Address
> $A$2:$C$4
```

Т.е. первая колонка тоже попадает в сортируемую область и именно она назначается заголовком, а все что ниже - подлежит сортировке. Значит, нужно вырезать эту строку из области сортировки

```
With [B2].CurrentRegion
  .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Sort [B1], xlAscending, Key2:=[C1], Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Answer (score -1):

Если выделив сортируемый диапазон, нажмете данные > сортировка, и в меню сортировки отметите "Мои данные содержат заголовки", тогда Ваш макрос будет сортировать как задумано.

PS: могу ошибаться, но в моих смутных воспоминаниях говорится о том, что программная сортировка не реагирует на опцию "Header = xlYes". И не смотря на это MS Excel лучший :).